# React: How many methods have ref.current?

Tags: reactjs, methods, click

I have a question:

In React we can use methods like focus(), blur(), click() in our useRef elements (ex: inputRef.current.click()), but how many methods exist? Others like change or onChange: have methods for them?

This is an example of problem with change event

```
            <input
                type="file"
                ref={ inputRef }
                onChange={ dropImage }
                style={ { display: "none" } }
            />

            <CardMedia
                component="img"
            
                image={ image }
                alt={ image}
                onDrop={ (e) => {
                    e.preventDefault()
                    inputRef.current.click() // I need associate with onChange instead of onClick
                } }
                onDragOver={ dragOver }
                onDragEnter={ dragEnter }
                onDragLeave={ dragLeave }
            />
```

Comment: `ref.current` when `ref` points to an element is the DOM element itself so whatever the DOM element have methods on it, it has all the same methods

Comment: Sure, but why **current.change()** doesn't work?

Comment: To which element you are applying, please show some code or a working sample (you can use codesandbox or stackblitz) ...

Comment: I edited the main post with a fragment of the problem